# Magento: “Add New Set” button in “Manage Attribute Sets” is not visible…

Tags: magento, attributes

For some reason the "Add New Set" buton is not visible in the "Manage Attribute Sets". Hope someone can help with this...

I have tried everything... gone through all settings... nothing seems to be wrong... Desperate as I was, I even made a complete reinstall on a clean site (and DB)... Same issue...

The "default" set is empty, and there are no unassigned attributes in the list... I think it's weird... (see attached images)

Anyone have an idea of what(if) I'm doing(something) wrong? Everything else seem to be working ok!

(thanks in advance)

Mike

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because there is template files missing in magento 1.9.2.3 version adminhtml catalog directory.
You will need to add the files from magento old version manually to make the attribute section work properly. you can find more detail here:
[magento attribute set missing button](http://www.crazywebdevelopers.com/add-attribute-set-button-not-showing-in-magento/)